# How to correctly predict values in a line?

Tags: approximation, data-analysis

I have data tables with statistical data per year of various figures. There are some gaps in the data, so I need to approximate the gaps. A simple linear extrapolation won't do because I might have some data similar to the following examples:

5 7 10 12 15 25 N/A 25 28 31 N/A 9 15 10 0 N/A N/A 0

Or I might have multiple interdependent sets of data like meat production and meat spoilage:

Meat production: 2 3 3 4 5 5 7 9 15 25 62 110

Meat spoilage: 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 4 N/A N/A N/A N/A

I'm sorry if a question like this is common or has been answered many times, I'm very inexperienced in math. so much so that I don't even know what area of math deals with these kind of things.

Comment: Not sure to see why a linear interpolation would not work in your examples.

Comment: I guess I was unclear about what I meant with "a simple linear interpolation*". I was referring to the interpolations where you interpolate between the first and last figures, which wouldn't be suitable for my first example, and I would need a more complicated interpolation that involves detecting peaks. Moreover, the "simple" linear interpolation would also focus on a singe array at a time, ignoring cause/effect relationships between sets of data or global trends. Perhaps the solution is a complex linear interpolation, but I have yet to figure that out. I welcome specific suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various mathematical techniques for estimating missing values in a data series. They all fall under the general heading of [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

If you have an idea about how one variable depends on another, and you want to asses the validity of this idea, then you need to know about [regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis).

In either case you need to have some idea about how you expect your data to behave (for example, you have already rejected linear interpolation) to give you a starting point.